# Use EAP-TTLS authentication with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04, authentication

My employer's wireless network requires EAP-TTLS authentication to log on. However, EAP-TTLS is not an option I can select in my wireless settings. How can I use EAP-TTLS on Ubuntu 20.02?

Comment: Quick google indicates wpa_supplicant supports EAP-TTLS [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wpa_supplicant) and [ubuntu man page for wpa_supplicant config](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/wpa_supplicant.conf.5.html) .. note: search page for EAP-TTLS.  I have no experience with EAP-TTLS, but this should get you headed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that TTLS stands for Tunneled-TLS. I used Tunneled-TLS for the authentification setting in the wireless network settings GUI instead of EAP-TTLS and it worked like a charm.